# Dim NewBarcode As New Barcode()

Tags: vb.net, barcode

In a class that I have in my web site I'm Importing

```
Imports IDAutomation.Windows.Forms.LinearBarCode
Imports IDAutomation.Windows.Forms
```

Also in the code I'm using

```
Dim NewBarcode As New Barcode()
```

That Line works fine when I'm running the site in debug mode in my PC localhost:3552
Finaly I'm uploading the code (the all site code) in my ISP Server, when program comes to this line

```
Dim NewBarcode As New Barcode()
```

It throws me an error with the following text.

> Showing a modal dialogbox or form when the application is not
>   running in UserInterface mode is not valid. Specify The
>   ServiceNotification or DefaultDeskTopOnly style to Display a
>   notification from a service application.

I searcher the Internet about that; but the issue I found was mention only for a messagebox.
 A control which I don't have it; and I'm not using it.
I suspect that the issue is coming from the

> IDAutomation.Windows.Forms
>   But I don't have any solution for this...

Is there anybody to know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You're using a library built for windows forms, not asp.net which are very different, ID automation appear to have an asp.net library here http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-components/aspx-generator-script/

Comment: Please write your answer normally in order to be able to give you credits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BarCode component you are using is made for winforms, rather than webforms, and will try to show the barcode dialog on the *web server*, not in the user's browser. It works while testing on your computer because the web server and the web browser are the same machine. When you try to move that code to a real web server, especially one using Windows Server Core (which has no gui), this is the result.